# what happened to dialogs in the facebook sdk beta?

Tags: objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

the old SDK has dialog methods to present a simple UI for various tasks. this call has been removed from the SDK beta, and there doesn't seem to be anything to replace it. how are we supposed to implement this stuff now?

Answer (score 6):

Are you referring to Facebook's [Dialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/)?

if so, those are supported in the 3.0 version of the iOS SDK via the `DeprecatedHeaders`

There are more details here, the example is specifically for the Feed Dialog:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-dialog-using-ios-sdk/

Answer (score 4):

Igy's answer is correct, and the link he listed is a good place to start when you need to [use the deprecated headers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-dialog-using-ios-sdk/).

Adding some details in terms of our plans; as you know we are starting to provide more native implementations for UI such as the FBFriendPickerViewController, etc. Meanwhile, there is still a need for UIWebView-based dialogs, and we will be adding additional support to the SDK for both native and webview dialogs. For now we are leaning on our backward compatibility with the previous SDK for dialog support. This gives us a chance to gather feedback on the direction we are taking the SDK, which will help to inform our future direction with dialogs and UI features in general.

Hopefully this helps to clarify the thinking a bit. We are eager to hear any feedback you have on the new UI components in the SDK. Thanks!

Comment: is there a way to send "apprequests" without using the deprecated API? i dont need dialogs for selecting friends, i have a list of userIDs picked from a custom view.